# Why does this SCSS result in a no-descending-specificity error?

Tags: sass, stylelint

This small SCSS block

```
a {
  color: red;
  &:hover {
    color: green;
  }
}

i {
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }  
}
```

Gives this error

**Expected selector "i a" to come before selector "a:hover"  no-descending-specificity**

But if I reverse the order

```
i {
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }  
}

a {
  color: red;
  &:hover {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

The error just reverses too

**Expected selector "a" to come before selector "i a"  no-descending-specificity**

Comment: Linters are arbitrary, in all honesty, and don't really tell you anything about how the code works. In the second case it just complains because `i a` is more specific than `a`, in the first that `i a` is less specific than `a:hover` (is it? havent' checked but its so arbitrary)...